# How to efficiently merge many columns of an R data.frame?

Tags: r

I'm trying to merge several hundred columns of a dataframe. Currently trying to do this with a for loop, which isn't working.

The columns are numbered 1 : n, lets say 512.

```
for(i in 1:512) {
    DF[as.numeric(i)] <-paste(DF[as.numeric(i)], DF[as.numeric(i)+1])  
}
```

(using the "as.numeric(i)" since I was getting errors when trying to select the next column)

*EDIT*

All the values are strings, with many rows not being filled till the 512 columns.  I'm trying to combine all the strings in 1 row into a single string.

Comment: You can use `apply(df, 1, paste0, collapse ="")`

Comment: it would be better if you can provide reproducible example. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `apply` with `paste0` as:

```
df <- data.frame(id = 1:10, name = rep(c("Test1", "Test2"),5), 
                 value = 101:110, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

apply(df, 1, paste0, collapse ="")

#Result
# [1] " 1Test1101" " 2Test2102" " 3Test1103" " 4Test2104" " 5Test1105" " 6Test2106"
# [7] " 7Test1107" " 8Test2108" " 9Test1109" "10Test2110"
```

Comment: muchas gracias <3